# PHP extract array into variables

Tags: php, arrays

i have following output i am trying to put individual values into separate variables

output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 8711 [1] => 200 [2] => 755 [3] => 1800 [4] => 01 [5] => 675 [6] => 8910 ) )
```

i have tried following code but no success.

```
echo extract($matches[0]);
```

please help me in this regard.

Comment: Extract won't work here since numbers aren't valid variable names. `$1` `$2` etc are not valid. variables must begin with a letter or underscore.

Comment: @Colin - extract will allow you to prefix the variable names

Comment: @MarkBaker True, but that's not being done here is it :D

Comment: @Colin, no, but it should be (though I'm unsure why OP doesn't not simply work with the array anyway)

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, in this case it should be in order for this to work. However I also just generally think that `extract` is a terrible function and it's list of legitimate uses cases is virtually non-existent. Working with the array is definitely the preferred choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its multi-dimensional array:
Try:

```
 echo $matches[0][0];
 echo $matches[0][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to sometimes see the array in a more readable format.

Try

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($matches) . '</pre>';
```

You can also specify:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($matches[0]) . '</pre>';
```

To limit data for that sub array.

If you just need to access one of your elements others have already shown how.

Ex.

> $arr = array('a'=>'alphabet', 'b'=>'better', 'c'=>array(1=>'cat',
>   2=>'click', 'z'=>'clean'));

To put 'clean' in a variable you'd use:

> $clean = $arr['c']['z'];

To put 'better' in a variable you'd use:

```
$better = $arr['b'];
```